# Configuring WebDriverIO and Appium for using different xpath for iOS and Android elements in one common page object file in mobile automation

Tags: appium, webdriver-io

I am working on mobile automation(iOS and Android). Some of the UI elements are not having the Accessibility IDs. So, I am using xpath and the xpath is different for iOS and android. I want to include xpath for both ios and android elements in one common page object file.
Now my query is: When I run the script on android device, it should pick android element's xpath and when I run the script on iOS it should pick ios element's xpath. Could anyone please help how to differentiate/configure the same.

I need how to configure the same.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, with webdriver-io there is no alternative besides using  ugly if-else statements or better, by implementing a [factory design pattern.](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method)

Answer (score 0):

If you can, go through the effort of adding the accessibility Id's to the elements. Using xpath will be brittle and harder to maintain.